# shopkick application UI widgets

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, uitabbar

Please see the link below.

http://itunes.apple.com/app/id383298204?mt=8

There are screen shots of showpick application. In that there is a collect button which is some what impossible to implement under ui tab bar. Can someone help me to figure it out how they have implemented it? Is that an actual UITabBar?

Thank you

Comment: I ran into the same issue. Apparently there are several Apps with this design. Is it even possible to use a UITabBarController for that, or do I have to reinvent everything?

Comment: Seems like its not possible with UITabBarItem. I used an image on top of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a workaround. I basically add a dummy controller for the middle entry of the UITabBarController. And in viewDidLoad I add a button to the UITabBar like so:

```
tabBarButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(125, -10, 70, 33)];
[tabBarButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"state-inactive"]forState:tabBarButton];
[topbarButtonScan setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"state-active"]forState:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[tabBarButton addTarget:self action:@selector(tabBarButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[[[self tabBarController]tabBar ] addSubview: tabBarButton];
```